# EventKit truncates result set when Time Zone Support is set to something other than the systemTimeZone

Tags: iphone, ios, eventkit, ekeventstore

In the iOS Settings app, there is a setting called "Time Zone Support" (Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Time Zone Support).  If this setting is **OFF**, there are no issues.  Also, if this setting is **ON**, but the Time Zone Support (TZS) time zone is set to the current value of `systemTimeZone`, there are also no issues.  *The only time there is a problem is if the setting is **ON** and the TZS time zone is set to a time zone other than `systemTimeZone`*.

In that final case, the array returned by the `eventsMatchingPredicate:` method (on instances of the `EKEventStore` class) is predictably truncated.  Given a query for all events that fall within a range of dates, instances of `EKEventStore` fail to return any events that fall between the start of the query range and the first midnight in the TZS time zone.

To provide an example, to retrieve all events for, say, 3/18/2013, one would issue a query for all events between 3/18/2013 12AM and 3/19/2013 12AM in the `systemTimeZone`.  Assuming the `systemTimeZone` is PDT, this would result in querying for all events between 3/18/2013 7AM GMT to 3/19/2013 7AM GMT (since PDT is GMT - 7 hours).  This query works fine with TZS OFF, as well as with TZS ON and set to PDT.  If TZS were ON and set to EDT, however, all events between the start of the query range and the first midnight in EDT would be missing from the resulting array.  Since EDT is GMT - 4 hours, the first midnight in EDT within the query range is 3/19/2013 4AM GMT.  All events between 3/18/2013 7AM GMT and 3/19/2013 4AM GMT would be missing, and the resulting array would only contain events between 3/19/2013 4AM GMT and 3/19/2013 7AM GMT.

This result is 100% predictable, both in the Simulator and on physical iOS devices (with any TZS time zone that I've tried).  I've tested on iOS 6 and iOS 6.1, with no noticeable differences in behavior.  Is there any reason that I'm missing as to why this could be the expected API behavior?  Also, despite much searching, there does not appear to be a public (or even private) API that allows a developer to determine whether TZS is ON or OFF, let alone any time zone that the user has set — making it difficult to think of a good workaround...  (Obviously, you could ensure that you don't miss any events by increasing the range of every query so that it will always include a midnight in any possible TZS time zone. Then, you could filter out extraneous events in code. However, for obvious reasons, I would like to avoid a hacky approach like this except as a last resort.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where certain events on the first day of the given NSDate range were not returned in the result. I found out that `[EKEventStore eventsMatchingPredicate]` seems to be influenced by the default time zone. This workaround eventually helped me out:

```
NSTimeZone *savedTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendars];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:savedTimeZone];
NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

I hope hope this also helps in your specific case (in my case the Date/time time zone of the user was different than the default time zone in the app, in your case the calendar time support is on, but it is probably the same scenario for 'predicateForEventsWithStartDate')

In my opinion it's a bug or design flaw in `[EKEventStore eventsMatchingPredicate]` because the given NSDates are already 'timezone-less' in the sense that they indicate a point-in-time, nothing time zone related.